# Referencing Glacier as Resource in CloudFormation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-glacier

Brand new to AWS and trying to put together a stack with a CloudFormation template.

The stack will have two EC2 Instances with a windows service running on each. Some of the storage will be on S3 and some will be on AWS Glacier.

I can't find samples or instructions on how to add Glacier as Resource in the CF Template.

Am I missing something and this is not possible through a CF template?

Has anyone done this before, and can someone provide a sample, if it is possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Glacier is best used for cold storage. It's essentially equivalent to tape storage. I suggest you use only S3 and then have a lifecycle rule where old data is moved from S3 to Glacier as @Anup Singh suggested. 

This is an old comment but retrieval costs can be significant: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4412886 

A newer blog article: https://iolap.com/2020/04/06/how-to-avoid-hidden-amazon-glacier-charges/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of 2013-02-27, CloudFormation does not support Glacier.

If/when it does, you'll see Glacier show up in the CloudFormation resource types documentation here:

> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-template-resource-type-ref.html

Any support for auto-migration from S3 to Glacier should show up here:

> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html

To register your desire for Amazon to work on this feature, add a +1 comment in this forum thread:

> https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=117947

Answer (score 2):

Workaround would be following:
Instead you can user the S3 rules to attach a Glacier policy OR S3 Lifecycle Rule. This rule will move the object automatically to the Glacier or even delete object after some time.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-lifecycleconfig-rule.html

Answer (score 0):

*AWS CloudFormation* has added support for custom resources, where you can use *AWS Lambda* functions to do the job of creating resources that *CloudFormation* doesn't natively support. The resource type in the *CloudFormation* template file would end up being *AWS::CloudFormation::CustomResource* or *Custom::String*

For more info, check these official AWS docs:

> 1. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cfn-customresource.html?shortFooter=true
> 2. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html?shortFooter=true